# Timer can be stopped in backgroundworker, but can't be started

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timer

Recently, I've been working with a `system.form.timer` in the `UI thread`. I've have noticed that while I can stop a timer on a background thread, I cannot start it back up unless I use `BeginInvoke` even though I do not receive a `cross-threading exception`. On a `system.timers.timer` however it seems that I can stop and start it from the background thread created by the timer. Why is this? Is a `system.form.timer` allowed to be stopped, but not enabled from a background thread? This seems a bit odd to me.

## System.Form.Timer Code

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim BW As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler BW.DoWork, AddressOf CheckTimer
    BW.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckTimer()
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
    MsgBox("Stopped and Started Timer")
End Sub
```

**WORKS**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim BW As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler BW.DoWork, AddressOf CheckTimer
    BW.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckTimer()
    Timer1.Stop()
    Me.BeginInvoke(New TimerStart(AddressOf TimerStartFunction))
    MsgBox("Stopped and Started Timer")
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub TimerStart()

Private Sub TimerStartFunction()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

## System.Timers.Timer Code

**WORKS**

```
Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(5000)
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
    aTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Sub OnTimedEvent()
    aTimer.Stop()
    aTimer.Start()
    MsgBox("Stopped and Started Timer")
End Sub
```

Comment: check `Me.InvokeRequired` and you'll notice its running on a diffrent thread then the UI hence it needs to be invoked. you can start and stop a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` when you declare it at the class level manually and not drag it on the form `Dim aTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Comment: actually i was lying, it will still be created on the UI thread and hence `InvokeRequired` will return True.

Comment: Why are you saying that the first code does not work? It works fine at my end.

Comment: A Timer is NOT a Form Control, it is a component, so it can be manipulated from other threads without invoking.

Comment: @varocarbas the code will run all the way through with no exceptions however if you step into debug mode and watch the controls you'll see that timer1 does not start back up again.

Comment: @UrielKatz perhaps is because of having the Option Strict Off, but in my quick test, I didn't see any problem; the timer started over and over again. I will do a new test right now.

Comment: I tested it again and it works (Option Strict On). Just a clarification: your code does not compile because you are not using the right arguments for  CheckTimer (you should write CheckTimer(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)). If you correct this issue, open a project, add a timer (enabled from the start) and write your code, you would see the messages coming over and over. I insist: don't see the problem (other than in your small error). Will take a look at the Hans Passant's answer and understand all this a bit better.

Comment: @vvarocarbas I don't see why having the sender and e arguments would make a difference, also I don't see the need for having option strict on. However, I tested it again without these and noticed something new. It only works when you step through it line by line.

Comment: @varocarbas I believe you're right, it seems the problem is in the way I'm testing the timer is working, that is by showing a message box. After looking at my output and pressing enter every few seconds I see that the timer is indeed working as it is creating threads. 
**Output:**
`The thread '<No Name>' (0x169c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1784) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a88) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: The given sub/function definition has to match the one of the delegate it is assigned to (because this what you are doing when using AddHandler). If your code compiles is because, most likely, option strict is off (you are telling VB.NET to be more tolerant and allow not-completely-right codes to compile). That's why my previous statement: perhaps I wasn't doing things completely right in my test. Although your point is correct: strict on/off has nothing to say on this front (neither I use strict off ever) it was just a generic justification ("the problem might be provoked by strict off")

Comment: Regarding your last statements, they don't make too much sense: there is no methodology better than any other one to determine if a code works or not. If the code runs fine (messagebox poping up regularly), running it step by step cannot output something different. Also I don't get the exact point you are trying to make in your last message. The only reason explaining why it doesn't work on your computer and works on mine is the low reliability of this configuration, as highlighted via comments in the Hans Passant's answer.

Comment: @varocarbas what's happening on mine is that although message boxes are showing up they are hiding for some reason. When stepping through it however the message boxes don't hide.  That is why if I press enter the code continues to execute and create threads. Perhaps it would be better to ensure that the message box is running on the UI thread using begin.invoke, but I'm not entirely sure this would change anything. Either way the parts relating to the timer still work.

Comment: As said (here and via comments in the answer below), the reason why we both get different behaviours is that this is not a completely right code which thus might drive to unreliable situations. But I insist: it works perfectly (messageboxes show the right behaviour) as I have done it, that is: open a new VS 2010 ( strict option on), put a timer called timer1 in your form, write your code (correct the arguments of CheckTimer as proposed) and execute it. What I usually do with BGW is calling any control methods from the GUI thread, just to make sure and thus I do recommend you to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Winforms Timer class is *somewhat* thread-safe, not enough to keep you happy.  When you call its Start() method then it creates a hidden window that turns WM_TIMER messages into Tick events.

When you do this on a worker thread then you tend to have a problem, these WM_TIMER messages are only dispatched when the thread runs a message loop.  Worker threads don't normally do this, they don't call Application.Run().  So the timer just won't tick.

Calling the Stop() method is otherwise okay, it knows how to find that hidden window back even through the code runs on the wrong thread.  The workaround you found with BeginInvoke() works because it now correctly calls Start() on the UI thread and gets the hidden window created with the correct owner thread, one that pumps.  System.Timers.Timer doesn't have this problem, it doesn't rely on WM_TIMER to tick but uses a System.Threading.Timer instead.  Which is supported by a dedicated worker thread managed by the CLR.  Do note that this timer is pretty dangerous.  Calling MsgBox() on a worker thread is fundamentally wrong, for one.  High odds that the user never sees it since it will be behind a UI window.

That explains it, I can't otherwise offer better advice since I can't see what you are really trying to do.  Be careful, you are playing with fire.

Comment: I am not in a position to argue with your statements. I personally never call any "control method" from a BGW thread just to make sure, but I have tested this code (the first one) and works fine. This statement is not completely against your argument "TEND to have a problem", but is something highlight-worthy:  if you add the first code to a new VS-2010 project, it works fine.

Comment: The word "tend" is intentional, it will arbitrarily work just fine when that hidden window is already created.